# DocumentDB STARTSWITH not working from .NET

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a collection named `Customer` and each entry has a property named `Number`. Here is the content of a select all command:

```
[
    { 
        "Number": "K1",
        "Label": "Test1"        
    },
    { 
        "Number": "T1",
        "Label": "Test2"        
    }
]
```

I use Azure Portal to fire the following query against this collection:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE STARTSWITH(c.Number, 'K')
```

This gives me the correct result:

```
[
    { 
        "Number": "K1",
        "Label": "Test1"        
    }
]
```

But when I do it in C# using the DocumentDB NuGet package:

```
var options = new FeedOptions();
var query = "SELECT * FROM c WHERE STARTSWITH(c.Number, 'K')";
var items = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Customer>(uri, options, query).ToList()
```

then it will retrieve all (in this case 2) items every time.

It seems as if `CreateDocumentQuery` ignores this statement completely.

**Edit**

The ActivityId for the query is `7f473650-f125-4b6b-9d4c-2d520deceebd`.

Comment: Some additional details will help identify the root cause. Can you please check what is the query text sent over the wire by running Fiddler? Or if you could paste a complete sample, or share the ActivityID for the query, that would help.

Comment: @AravindRamachandran I added the activity in the post. I can't check Fiddler because I can't get Fiddler to work properly with https. I can't see any URLs there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the definition of `CreateDocumentQuery`, its parameters are `uri`, `query`, `options`..., if you place options instead of query, it will default query as null, so you only get all items in the collection.

```
public IQueryable<T> CreateDocumentQuery<T>(Uri documentCollectionOrDatabaseUri, SqlQuerySpec querySpec, FeedOptions feedOptions = null, object partitionKey = null);
```

Change it to:

```
var items = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Customer>(uri, query, options).ToList()
```

Comment: I had a slightly different experience.  I only got bad results if I used the `STARTWITH` verb.  If I just checked for equality, I got the correct results back.  Anyway, this helped fix the problem.  thanks.